# Ics file handline multiple timezones

Tags: timezone, icalendar

I have a PHP script that creates an ICS file, the file is synced with an Iphones calender via a web view and this works fine. However now my Iphone app is used all over the world I get people asking to have the entries in there own time zone, is there an easy way to do this

Currently I specify a timezone

X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London

And then add the entries as follows

DTSTART:20121130T194500

Is it simply a case of changing the timezone or do I calculate the new time in that timezone as well

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for timezone handling you should refer to [rfc5545 and vtimezone definition][1].

basically you need to define the timezone

> 

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19670430T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=4;BYDAY=-1SU;UNTIL=19730429T070000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
```

and then refer to it in your events so:

> 

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T090000
```

it should be noted that `X-WR-TIMEZONE` is an Apple iCal specific tag and nto part of the standard
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5